# Proper robotic competitions for one university team (first step)

Tags: design

I am **Bioengineering** student at one Iranian middle-rank university and have a small business in building some easy medical devices (**PCB** and **CAD** designing with **Programming** and some **market** experiments). So, one of my interests is finding teams of student during this study for my business, so interested in one of the university teams which just now in our university started to create and grow as one **robotic team** with 25 members in telegram group until now.

As a rule, One of its goals is to participate in **robotic champions**, so I like to know about your **suggestion** on what are the best fields of work with some **fundamental** knowledge with encouraging new students to work on it and have fun with better grow learning during this teamwork? (Also, maybe it would be good to consider the quarantine situation because of Covid-19)

I googled the [**Robotics competitions types in world**](https://www.google.com/search?q=Robotics+competitions+types+in+world&oq=Robotics+competitions+types+in+world&aqs=chrome..69i57j33l5.6942j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), and found some results like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Robotics_competitions) that could be useful to choose from them:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I would love to be a part of this. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Soheil Paper, but I'm afraid that questions like this really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works. Also, the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) has good advice on how to write a good question. If you edit your question to fit our community guidelines we can reopen it for you.